# Kotlin app crashes after creating database, can not write to database file on first run only (locked)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

On the first run of an app that creates an SQLite database, the app crashes with errors relating to being unable to use the SQLite database file (locked). This only happens on the first run and the app runs successfully on every other run.

I believe that when the database class is being instantiated and the database is being created for the first time, the app tries to use it too soon after its creation (or slightly before and/or during creation) which is causing the crash.

The database is created in the onCreate section of the "DatabaseHelper" class I created. DatabaseHelper is being instantiated in the main activity of the app..

Any ideas how I can tell the app to pause for a second or so to allow the creation of the database on first-run?

Thanks

CODE SNIPPETS:

DatabaseHelper & DB creation:

```
class DatabaseHelper(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION),
    PurchasesUpdatedListener, BillingClientStateListener, AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener {

    companion object {
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "acwa8fz4wo93o28v4"
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 10
  }

   override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        Log.i("MSG", "trying to create DB")

        val CREATE_MY_TABLE = (

                "create table products (" +
                        "productName text, " +
                        "productId text, " +
                        "productDesc text, " +
                        "productLongDesc text, " +
                        "updateFlag bool)"

                )

        db.execSQL(CREATE_MY_TABLE)

        Log.i("MSG", "Created DB")

}
```

Instantiation of DatabaseHelper in MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    val dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(this, null)  <-- I believe this is where the DB gets created for the first time if not exist..

    //more stuff in Activity below...
```

Error message excerpts:

```
2021-04-21 07:15:17.094 11360-11360/com.domain.app I/MSG: trying to create DB
2021-04-21 07:15:17.096 11360-11360/com.domain.app I/MSG: Created DB
2021-04-21 07:15:20.039 11360-11419/com.domain.app E/SQLiteLog: (5) database is locked in "PRAGMA journal_mode"
2021-04-21 07:15:20.042 11360-11419/com.domain.app E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.domain.app/databases/acwa8fz4wo93o28v4'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5 SQLITE_BUSY): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:405)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:345)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:258)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:918)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:762)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:751)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:373)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:340)
        at com.domain.app.dao.DatabaseHelper.verify(DatabaseHelper.kt:197)
        at com.domain.app.ListActivity.verify(ListActivity.kt:522)
        at com.domain.app.ListActivity.access$verify(ListActivity.kt:35)
        at com.domain.app.ListActivity$onCreate$$inlined$schedule$1.run(Timer.kt:149)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
2021-04-21 07:15:20.127 11360-11419/com.domain.com W/SQLiteOpenHelper: Opened acwa8fz4wo93o28v4 in read-only mode
```

Additional stack trace with crash

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-04-21 16:34:10.594 17236-17270/com.kaboserv.statestatute E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: verify
    Process: com.domain.app, PID: 17236
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5 SQLITE_BUSY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLong(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:750)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLong(SQLiteSession.java:654)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong(SQLiteStatement.java:109)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:1017)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:1005)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion(SQLiteDatabase.java:1093)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:389)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:340)
        at com.domain.app.dao.DatabaseHelper.verify(DatabaseHelper.kt:197)
        at com.domain.app.ListActivity.verify(ListActivity.kt:529)
        at com.domain.app.ListActivity.access$verify(ListActivity.kt:36)
        at com.domain.app.ListActivity$onCreate$$inlined$schedule$1.run(Timer.kt:149)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

Comment: You seem to have missed actually including the error and the code it refers to in your question.

Comment: The error says it cannot find the database file. After it says it was created by my log message. I will update the post to include the full message tomorrow...

Comment: The database file doesn't get created when you instantiate the helper. It gets created on the first call to e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`

Comment: ok, that is a good clue, so you suggest I use a timer when making my first call to this function?

Comment: A closer look at the error message actually says the database is locked and it opens a read only copy. So I now think it may be my first call to ```getWritableDatabase()```

Comment: I did indeed find that it fails on the first instance of using a writable database after install. I will work on a fix and post an answer later tonight. Thanks for the insight..

Comment: The stacktrace does not look like a crash, FATAL EXCEPTION is missing, it's more just like a caught and logged exception. Anyway. in that trace `DatabaseHelper.verify()` is the first part to check since it's where your code moves to the framework code.

Comment: I added additional stack trace that does show a crash, bit it only happens periodically, I do see that it appears to be in the verify function. In this function, it opens a readable database, then if no data, it tries to open a writable database and this error shows.. I think thats the cause, going to try to fix now, will update question if thats the case.. thx @laaito

Comment: I think it's a bad idea for applications to be creating databases at runtime.  That can't scale.  Why do you think it's necessary to do so?  A better approach would be to create a general schema using DDL, start the database, and let the application manipulate it using DML.

Comment: I figured out what was happening, I was trying to add the entries to the database on first-run, while at the same time trying to verify all the items made it into the database. As to the reason I decided to do it this way, it started small... now its large, yes the scaling is an issue at this point. any links to what your talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was..

What I was doing is:

on first-run, create the database and populate it with all of the items I have stored in an array temporarily.

At the same time, I have a function (verify) that runs to check that all items from the array made it into the database (mainly to detect additions to the entries that need to be added). This verify func went thru each item in the array and checked to see if it exists in the DB, if not, it created it..

It was failing because it was conflicting with the initial entering things on first-run.. The crashes were when it tried to add an item that, by then, already exists...

I fixed it by checking for run counts and only "verifying" after the first run.